# In the Applications I have two 'Files' apps

Tags: applications, icons, files

I just installed eOS today and after 6 hours I am pretty happy with the environment while all of the tasks I feel so far I need to be able to accomplish have been covered. 
Question, in the Applications in the top left corner, two 'Files' icons-applications have appeared. The first one describes itself as 'Browse your files' while the second describes itself as 'Access and organize files'. What is up? :)
I have attached a screenshot as well.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Access and organize files" is Nautilus. You can rename the icon in `/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop`

Comment: Hello Cristian, thank you for your reply. Your response makes sense but I cannot change the name, pls see screenshot 
attachedfile:///home/neos/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot%20from%202017-12-16%2013.03.46.png

Comment: In Terminal: `sudo scratch-text-editor /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop`. Then change Name=Files to Name=Nautilus.

Comment: Do I need nautilus? How can I remove it? It has ugly interface https://i.stack.imgur.com/APPFQ.png "Files" looks much better... https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKzUb.png